# Return value from Ajax callback?

Tags: javascript, callback, enyo

I have a JavaScript class that handles queries to a local DB (on a WebOs device). Now what I want to do is, create a model with all my basic queries to simplify my code.

So first I create a function:

```
getLists: function(){
          this.query( 'SELECT * FROM lists ORDER BY rowID DESC', { 
                onSuccess:  enyo.bind(this,function(data) { this.getData(data); } ), 
                onError: function() { return false; } } );
   }
```

And than I have my callback function which receives the data:

```
getData: function(data){
       return data;
   }
```

Now what I would like to do, is call it like this from my app:

```
var data = getLists();
```

The problem is, this is not returning the data from my callback function (getData). My question is how can I have "getLists" return the data from the callback?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't get to.  The first A in AJAX is Asynchronous.  The requests happen "out of time" with the other processing.  Your call to `getLists` returns after it launches the AJAX request, and the callback function is called when the remote server responds to the AJAX request.

-- Edited for comments --

If you want to "watch" a variable you can use something like this:

```
// Set up a container for the data to return to.
var retData;

// Modify the getData function to assign to the global variable
getData: function (data) {
  retData = data;
}

// Start the "wait" process.
var myInterval = setInterval(function () {
  if (retData == undefined) {
    return;
  }

  // when the return data shows up stop waiting.
  clearInterval(myInterval);

  // some other data processing here in this function
  // or trigger the actual processing function.
  // don't have to pass retData to it, it's global, the 
  // data handler function can retrieve it itself.
  myDataHandler();
}, 1000);

// make the ajax call here.
getLists();
```

Comment: I know, that's why I created a callback function. My question is, how can I get the data from my callback function, using minimal code?

Comment: @levi - Either process the returned data in your callback function, or assign it to a global variable / call another global function and pass the data to it.

Comment: i see what you are saying. But how could I know when that global variable is set? I want to be able to make this call/get the data, from something like: data = myCall(). Is this possible?

Comment: @levi - No, generally not.  I'll modify my answer to include code to "watch" a variable and operate when it finds contents there, but it's not an ideal approach.  Your success callback function should either process the data, or hand it off to a function that does process it.

Comment: Gotcha. I may need to re-think how I do my queries

Answer (score 2):

You're thinking imperial: C follows B follows A. Forget about that.

AJAX and modern JavaScript works differently. You never say "get data now", you say "call X when data is available".

So the solution is to write some code which does something useful with the data. Let's call this function `a`. Instead of:

```
var data = conn.getData();
a( data );
b( data );
c( data );
```

you do

```
conn.getData( a ); // a has to call b which calls c.
```

Eventually, the data will be there and `a` will be called with `data` as an argument.

See? You don't chain calls to `a()` and `b()` as in traditional programming. Instead, you create functions that do what you want and pass those functions around.